# PHP sdk Exception 602: url string is not a member of the link_stat table

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I have a question about an Exception that was sent me when trying to extract dynamically Facebook like count.

Here is the example:

```
$ret = $facebook->api(array(
                            'method' => 'fql.query',
                            'query' => 'SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 
                " http://www.example.com/annunci   /"'.bSearchUrl($loc,$cat,$scat).'"'.$a[IdAnnuncio].'"'
                            ));
```

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 602: annunci is not a member of the link_stat table. thrown in C:\wamp\www\php-sdk\base_facebook.php

What does it mean?

In which way /annunci should be a member of the link_stat table?

Comment: That will most likely be due to the weird spacing and how you are using the double quotes in the query you are build there. Make a debug output of the value, and you’ll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error message says, FQL you are running is wrong. Try your FQL [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Refer [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) for more information.